# Calling Python (Miniconda) from Matlab 2017b

Tags: python, matlab, import, conda

I am trying to run a basic MATLAB example in which I can directly call python libraries using the `py` command. I got miniconda installed and the path is provided to MATLAB with `pyversion`:

```
>> pyversion

       version: '3.6'
    executable: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\pythonw.exe'
       library: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\python36.dll'
          home: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3'
      isloaded: 1
```

I can run the following example in MATLAB successfully:

```
%% Convert a Python String to a MATLAB String
wrapped = py.textwrap.wrap(T);
```

However, I cannot run the following even though I have installed numpy in conda:

```
>> a = py.numpy.sqrt(2)
Undefined variable "py" or class "py.numpy.sqrt".
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Edit: I have confirmed that this issue happens on MATLAB 2017b. It works on 2014b. Still need help to figure out what is going wrong on 2017b.

Comment: I get the same issue with MATLAB 2016b and Python 3.5.4 in a conda environment. I note that 2016b doesn't officially support Python 3.6 so I assume 2014b doesn't either, but that's obviously not your issue if 2014b works!

Comment: Based on a bit of reading around I suspect the problem may be that numpy is trying to load a different version of a library from the one used by MATLAB. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this other than by trying different versions of numpy, which will be painful but at least possible thanks to conda environments.